# Why are some images red in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

In cocos2d using "TexturePacker" essential version software and generate the .plist and sprite image it make some  images red..any one having solution…???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using the essential version and this is the developers' method of restricting features.

[Purchase the full version](http://sites.fastspring.com/codeandweb/product/all) and all sprites will be the correct colour.